# Is it possible to convert a MacBook Pro from the glossy to the matte option?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair

I have foolishly managed to crack the glass on the glossy screen of my 15 inch Mid 2010 MacBook Pro.

While considering the option to replace the glass, I then remembered I'd always wanted to have the matte (anti-glare) option.

1. Is it possible to convert from the glossy to the matte option? Is it as simple as removing the glass and installing a bezel?
2. Or are there more parts to the matte screen than this?
3. Or is it a completely different LCD panel?
4. Are there any other caveats, particularly with respect to the bezels that seem to be available on eBay and the like?

---

Edit: Should have mentioned that I already have the high-resolution glossy display.

Comment: If you just cracked the fromt glass, apple can replace all the cosmetic damage and give you a 90 day factory warranty for a fixed cost. Have you called them for a quote?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is completely different type of display. The antiglare is a higher resolution and has different bezel, so it's not possible to upgrade an existing display, short of using a screen film with it.

You would have to get this done through either an Apple Authorized Service Provider (AASP) or an Apple Store. The Apple Store almost definitely will not put something on the MacBook Pro that it didn't come with, but an AASP might. The only way to find out is to ask!

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have the high-resolution glossy display - does this make a difference?

Comment: Unfortunately not. On the antiglare display, it's not just a different type of glass. There is no glass! If I could show you them side by side it would make sense, unfortunately the internet isn't that advanced yet ;)

Comment: I see - I just sort of assumed that underneath the glass there was the matt display hiding. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Sorry that wasn't the answer you were looking for. Another thing you might look into is purchasing a used antiglare display from eBay or something and installing it. It's pretty straight forward as long as you move over the AirPort Card, alight the display correctly and ground yourself. I'm sure there's a manual out there.